# Flex-wrap fails when switching to mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

A simple flex-wrap setting works properly when I change the window size (narrower window forces wrap, as expected). However, when I switch to mobile emulation (on Chrome 70.0), despite the change in size, the two boxes appear either side-by-side or stacked (wrapped), depending on their configuration before I shifted to mobile. In other words, if the window was wide to begin with, then the boxes will *not* wrap and will remain side-by-side.

Loading directly in mobile emulation mode, I get the boxes side-by-side, despite the narrow width of the emulated mobile page.

Not sure what am I missing here. Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
<style type="text/css">
  div.flexrow { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; padding-left: 20px }
  div.header { border: 1px solid black; min-width: 320px; flex-grow: 1 }
  div.content { border: 1px solid black; min-width: 320px; flex-grow: 1 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="flexrow">
  <div class="header">
    <h3>Section H3 header</h3>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ol>
      <li>List item 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit.</li>
      <li>List item two. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit.</li>
      <li>List item the third. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

I'm using either Pixel 2XL, or iPhone X, or any of several other emulated mobile options on Chrome.

Comment: Please use flex-basis for the 100% width on the items.instead if the flex grow.

Comment: can you please add code link so i can run here?You can write some media query as well like flex direction:column; for the mobile .

Comment: Sumit Kumar, using flex-basis ("fill" or "content") in the "flexrow" div, while removing the flex-grow setting, did not help.

Comment: please try to usemedia query for achieving results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's Chrome on mobile being too smart for its own good in handling sizing of fonts on mobile. The solution: turn that feature off by adding

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

at the head block of your HTML.